# Python transposing multiple dataframes in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a few dataframes which are similar (in terms of number of rows and columns) to the 2 dataframes listed below

```
0    email           factor1_final   factor2_final   factor3_final
1    john@abc.com    85%             90%             50%
2    peter@abc.com   80%             60%             60%
3    shelby@abc.com  50%             70%             60%
4    jess@abc.com    60%             65%             50% 
5    mark@abc.com    98%             50%             60%
```

```
0    email           item1           item2           
1    john@abc.com    80%             60%             
2    peter@abc.com   60%             90%             
3    shelby@abc.com  900%            40%             
4    jess@abc.com    70%             35%            
5    mark@abc.com    92%             50%
```

my desired output is to have multiple dataframes with the email as column header and the factor or item as rows

```
email     john@abc.com   peter@abc.com   shelby@abc.com   jess@abc.com   mark@abc.com
factor1     85%          80%             50%              60%            98%
factor2     90%          60%             70%              65%            50% 
factor3     50%          60%             60%              50%            60%
```

I am able to get the result by transposing each dataframe individually using this but i'd like to create a for loop as i have several dataframes to transpose

```
#Set index to email and transpose
df1 = df1.set_index('email').T
df1
```

wrote something like this but the dataframes do not get transposed. Would like to directly change the dataframes in the list of dataframes (somewhere along the lines of inplace=True). Was wondering if there is something i am missing, appreciate any form of help, thank you.

```
#Create a list of all the dataframes
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]

for df in df_list:
    df = df.set_index('email').T

df1

#tried this too but does not work 
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i] = df_list[i].set_index('email').T
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me second solution working, here is small alternative:

```
df_list = [df1, df2]

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i] = df.set_index('email').T

print (df_list[0])
email         john@abc.com peter@abc.com shelby@abc.com jess@abc.com  \
factor1_final          85%           80%            50%          60%   
factor2_final          90%           60%            70%          65%   
factor3_final          50%           60%            60%          50%   

email         mark@abc.com  
factor1_final          98%  
factor2_final          50%  
factor3_final          60%  

print (df_list[1])
email john@abc.com peter@abc.com shelby@abc.com jess@abc.com mark@abc.com
item1          80%           60%           900%          70%          92%
item2          60%           90%            40%          35%          50%
```

Solution with create new list of DataFrames:

```
dfs = [df.set_index('email').T for df in df_list]
```

Comment: yep it works, but is there a way for the dataframes in df_list to be replaced such that df1,df2 etc are showing the transposed dataframes?

Comment: @wjie08 - no, it is not possible generally, because working with list. You need forget for `df1, df2` and used instead `df_list[0]`, `df_list[1]`

Comment: @wjie08 - It should working only if all opearation are inplace, o e .g. `transpose` is not inplace, so cannot do it here.